# Posting image files with Flutter to nodejs backend

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to post base64 enconded image to my nodejs backend service. However, im getting this error:
`I/flutter (10367): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast`

My json request is:

```
    http.post(nodeEndPoint, body: {
      "id": {
        "image": idBase64Image,
        "name": idFileName,
        "description": "ID File"
      },
      "pof": {
        "image": pofBase64Image,
        "name": pofFileName,
        "description": "Proof of Residence File"
      }
    }).then((res) {
       print(res.statusCode);
    }).catchError((err) {
      print(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create body like this:

```
  Map data = {
    "id": {
      "image": idBase64Image, 
      "name": idFileName, 
      "description": "ID File"
    },
    "pof": {
      "image": pofBase64Image, // make sure this is string
      "name": pofFileName,
      "description": "Proof of Residence File"
    }
  };


//encode Map to JSON
var body = json.encode(data);

http.post(nodeEndPoint,
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: body
  ).then((res) {
       print(res.statusCode);
    }).catchError((err) {
      print(err);
    });
```